# How should I clean up my thread? [Specific case]

Tags: windows, multithreading, visual-studio, visual-c++

My thread is some kind of infinite loop-style, at least in most cases. I won't give exact copypaste of my func, but actually the scheme is the following (pseudo):

```
thread()
{
   Allocate memory dynamically

   while(...)
   {
       ... do my job ...
   }

   Free memory
}
```

My application can trigger quit from quite many place, so wouldn't like to modify each of them. Do you guys know any already existing callback or something similar which can signal my thread that it should end & free up things? You, know actually some kind of function which gets called before Thread termination.

Edit: Stupid thing, but I must support Windows XP too. Don't ask, I can't do anything against it :/ So, I would need APIs which aren't Vista+.

Comment: So it quits only when the process is dying anyway? Why would you free memory that is about to be freed anyway?

Comment: Clean shutdown is hard. If you're sure it's something you really want to do, you'll need something that tracks all the things that need to be done before your process can terminate (and, in some cases, the order in which they need to be done). Call it's termination handler to shut down your process and code this thread to check whether it should shut down. Basically, code what you need and don't expect it to be easy or simple.

Comment: Well, it might not be needed at all, I just heard in school that it's the best to free memory before exiting, that's why I wanted to do it :)

Comment: You are asking for two different things. The standard way to signal a thread to terminate is to use [event objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655.aspx), and let the thread clean up after itself. If you need a callback when a thread terminates, you could use a DLL's `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` notification. From your question, it's not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: If you're talking about cleaning up on process exit, you could always use `atexit()`.  But only if it really is necessary, e.g., you have data that has to be saved; you don't need to free memory, close handles, etc., since the OS will do all that for you, and much more efficiently than you could.

Comment: Thanks :) By the way, I've got one question, which I can't test at the moment. At the moment, when atexit() function is called, are other threads already suspended/killed or is it possible that race condition happens? (for example if I'm doing something a little bit longer in my atexit, will my other threads be running meanwhile?)
Thanks again :)